# How clear error gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have designing in my web page.

I have used the gridview, I have used the gridview `delete` option. Get the following error,

> Multiple controls with the same ID
>   'Ddl' were found. FindControl requires
>   that controls have unique IDs.

My code is as follows,

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
   Label Amount = (Label)(DisplayGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblAmount"));
 Label Account = (Label)(DisplayGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlAccount"));
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt = CreateDataTable();
   dt = (DataTable)Session["myDatatable"];
   dt.DefaultView.AllowDelete = true;



   dt.DefaultView.Delete(e.RowIndex);
   dt.AcceptChanges();

   Session["myDatatable"] = dt;

        BindGrid();
    }
```

Comment: I should be getting +10 for this edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GridView has 2 controls with id `Ddl`, and hence you're getting the error,

> Multiple controls with the same ID
>   'Ddl' were found. FindControl requires
>   that controls have unique IDs.

Change the `id` of the control in your GridView to (say) `Ddl2`, you're error will be resolved.